# What is the exact number of Elohim in Demon: The Fallen?

Tags: world-of-darkness, demon-the-fallen

I remember that in one of the books of *Demon: The Fallen* the exact number of Elohim that exist is mentioned. It was somewhere in the ballpark of 100 million and a bit more, with the total amount only including ones and zeroes.

However, I cannot find exactly which book this was. I am 90% certain that it was in the core rulebook, and if so it's likely somewhere in the first four chapters, but for the love of Lucifer I cannot find the exact number that is mentioned. Does anyone know what the number is, and in which book on what page it is mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Demon: the Fallen, page 37:

> Understand that fully a third of the Heavenly Host had fallen by
>   Lucifer's side. We numbered thirty million, three hundred thousand and
>   thirty. And of our number, only two — Amiel and Ank-Rhuhi — failed in
>   their courage and returned for punishment.

Assuming that "fully a third" is an exact number, its ninety million Nine-hundred thousand and ninety or 90,900,090.  100 million is a good enough ball-park figure for most cases though.